# Sending Euro using USD paypal account that is funded via EUR CC/bank account

Tags: paypal, eur-euro, usd-us-dollar

The title says it all. I want to send money to a seller in Europe, naturally he billed me in EUR, and I have a EUR credit card connected to Paypal account. However my Paypal itself is in USD. What happens if I send EUR payment funded from EUR credit card via Paypal? Will EUR-USD-EUR conversion take place (which would cost me a lot, I presume, and I want to avoid that)?

Thank you.

Comment: Ask PayPal? I've seen no evidence that we have anyone participating here who understands the guts of their system.